# I need to display the information of a student when a particular student id is input in the text field of a windows form application

Tags: c#, ado.net

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM student details WHERE StudentID=@StudentID";
```

how do I modify it to include the user input student id in the above program statement?

Comment: This question makes no sense. Please read [**this**](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, use this :

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentID", int.Parse(yourTextBox.Text));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want this (although your question is a little vague):

```
int studentId;
if (int.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out studentId)) {
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentID", studentId);
}
```